# Create sorted list from dictionary of 2 keys and 2 tuples

Tags: python, tuples

Trying to create a function which I can use to create a sorted list from two keys and two tuples as the values.  I am having an issue somewhere with my "for" loop in that it will for some reason only print the key and the first tuple.  Somehow, the second tuple never gets passed through the sorter.

```
def printDictionary(dictionaryParm):
    for x in dictionaryParm:
    header = []
    header.append(x)

    for y in dictionaryParm.values():
       value = list(y)
       value.sort()

    output = header + value
    for item in output:
        print item

dictionaryTest = dict()
dictionaryTest["Key 1"] = ("234","123","345")
dictionaryTest["Key 2"] = ("456","678","567")

printCourseDictionary(dictionaryTest)
```

My guess is that there is an issue somewhere with the "for y" statement, but after a few versions, having included breaks and whatnot, I still cannot get the output correct.

Ideally, output should be something like this:

```
Key 1
123
234
345
Key 2
456
567
678
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Your indentation is off, please fix it, we can't tell if the `output = header + value` part of the code is inside or outside of the `for y in dictionaryParam.values():` loop.

Comment: Honestly, that's probably where I am having the issue (indentation).  If I move it inside the "for y" statement, the issue becomes that the output is completely off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have some indentation problems, but if I understood you right you need following code

```
def printDictionary(dictionaryParm):
    for x in dictionaryParm:
        header = [x]

        value = list(dictionaryParm[x])
        value.sort()

        output = header + value
        for item in output:
            print(item)

dictionaryTest = dict()
dictionaryTest["Key 1"] = ("234","123","345")
dictionaryTest["Key 2"] = ("456","678","567")

printDictionary(dictionaryTest)
```

Code output

```
Key 2
456
567
678
Key 1
123
234
345
```

Comment: This is fixed it.  I understand how this works, as it basically added the values to the list containing the header, but why does this work and append does not?  I feel like append would work, but I was doing something wrong with how I was concatenating things.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is @ indentation in loop where in value to be sorted and added. is this address your issue ?? 

`def printDictionary(dictionaryParm):
    for k, y in dictionaryParm.items():
        value = list(y)
        value.sort()
        output = ([k]+ value)
        for it in output:
            print (it)
dictionaryTest = dict()
dictionaryTest["Key 1"] = ("234","123","345")
dictionaryTest["Key 2"] = ("456","678","567")
printDictionary(dictionaryTest)

Output code

Key 1
123
234
345
Key 2
456
567
678`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def printDictionary(dictionaryParm):

    for x in dictionaryParm:
        header = []
        header.append(x)

        #print header

        value=list(dictionaryParm.get(x))
        print value
        output = header + value
        for item in output:
            print item

dictionaryTest = dict()
dictionaryTest["Key 1"] = ("123","234","345")
dictionaryTest["Key 2"] = ("456","567","678")

printDictionary(dictionaryTest)
```